# Преобразование таблицы (UNPIVOT) в Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

При преобразовании таблиц с Росстата столкнулся с проблемой. Как с pandas на python  расформировать сводную таблицу в плоскую
преобразовать полученные таблицы вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[data.csv](https://yadi.sk/i/I-8os85zb5J73g):

```
;;Jan 2018 I;Jan 2019 II;Feb 2018 I;Feb 2019 II
48;Lip;12.0;14.0;16.0;12.0
47;Len;0.0;0.7;0.5;0.2
50;Mos;43.0;45.0;38.8;36.4
```

в такой вид:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете добавить пример входных данных текстом, а не картинкой?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/I-8os85zb5J73g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

Читаем данные:

```
In [6]: df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\download\data.csv", sep=";", index_col=[0,1])

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
        Jan 2018 I  Jan 2019 II  Feb 2018 I  Feb 2019 II
48 Lip        12.0         14.0        16.0         12.0
47 Len         0.0          0.7         0.5          0.2
50 Mos        43.0         45.0        38.8         36.4
```

Решение:

```
In [8]: df.stack()
Out[8]:
48  Lip  Jan 2018 I     12.0
         Jan 2019 II    14.0
         Feb 2018 I     16.0
         Feb 2019 II    12.0
47  Len  Jan 2018 I      0.0
         Jan 2019 II     0.7
         Feb 2018 I      0.5
         Feb 2019 II     0.2
50  Mos  Jan 2018 I     43.0
         Jan 2019 II    45.0
         Feb 2018 I     38.8
         Feb 2019 II    36.4
dtype: float64
```

Решение (без мульти-индекса):

```
In [9]: df.stack().reset_index()
Out[9]:
    level_0 level_1      level_2     0
0        48     Lip   Jan 2018 I  12.0
1        48     Lip  Jan 2019 II  14.0
2        48     Lip   Feb 2018 I  16.0
3        48     Lip  Feb 2019 II  12.0
4        47     Len   Jan 2018 I   0.0
5        47     Len  Jan 2019 II   0.7
6        47     Len   Feb 2018 I   0.5
7        47     Len  Feb 2019 II   0.2
8        50     Mos   Jan 2018 I  43.0
9        50     Mos  Jan 2019 II  45.0
10       50     Mos   Feb 2018 I  38.8
11       50     Mos  Feb 2019 II  36.4
```

PS переименовать столбцы можно воспользовавшись [DataFrame.rename(columns={"col1_name":"new_name1", "...":"..."})](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html)...